# Interacting with TFVC API from Build Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-build-task, tfvc

I'm trying to use the TFVC API from a build task without using Personal Access Token.

I've read that if I'll use the Client SDK it should authenticate automatically but I'm failing to get it working.

Another alternative I'm considering is to run tf.exe but it requires authentication as well.

Basically I would like to get the changesets for a certain build using my Build Task with minimum info from the user (hence I don't want Personal Access Token or Username/Password).

Is that doable?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to authenticate with an OAuth token. It's populated in the build variable `$(System.AccessToken)` or the environment variable `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`.

You provide it to the REST API with the header Authorization set to *Bearer [token]*, where *[token]* is the OAuth token value.

Comment: Thanks.
Mind posting a sample as I'm banging my head with task for several days? I'll highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you queue a build with TFVC repository and then check the logs for "Get Sources" step, you will find how to use TF.exe to get source during the build.And then you can copy the command and use it in a CommandLine/PowerShell task like following:
[image]

Make sure that "Allow Scripts to access token" option is enabled.